# Erro ao criar tabelas com chaves estrangeiras

Tags: mysql

Ao correr o *script* abaixo ocorre o erro:

> Cannot add foreign key constraint

ao criar as últimas duas tabelas.

```
create database Cinema;
use Cinema;

create table Filme (
    id_filmes int primary key auto_increment not null,
    nome_BR varchar (45) not null,
    nome_EN varchar (45) not null,
    anoLanccamento int not null,
    sinopse varchar (45) not null,
    fk_id_diretor int,
    fk_id_genero int,
    constraint foreign key (fk_id_diretor) references diretor (id_diretor),
    constraint foreign key (fk_id_genero) references genero (id_genero)
)engine = InnoDB;

create table Funcionario (
    id_funcionario  int primary key auto_increment,
    nome varchar (45) not null,
    carteiraTrabalho int not null,
    dataContratacao date not null,
    salario float not null
)engine = InnoDB; 

create table diretor (
    id_diretor int primary key auto_increment,
    nome varchar (45) not null
)engine = InnoDB;

create table genero (
id_genero int primary key auto_increment,
nome varchar (45) not null
)engine = InnoDB;

create table funcao (
    id_funcao int primary key auto_increment,
    nome varchar (45) not null
)engine = InnoDB;

create table horario (
    id_horario int primary key auto_increment,
    hora time not null
)engine = InnoDB;

create table sala (
    id_sala int primary key auto_increment,
    nome varchar (45) not null,
    capacidade int 
)engine = InnoDB;

create table premiacao (
    id_premiacao int primary key auto_increment,
    nome varchar (45) not null,
ano int 
)engine = InnoDB;

create table horario_trabalho_funcionario(
    fk_id_horario int,
    fk_id_funcionario int,
    fk_id_funcao int ,
    constraint foreign key (fk_id_horario) references horario (id_horario),
    constraint foreign key (fk_id_funcionario) references funcionario (id_funcionario),
    constraint foreign key (fk_id_funcao) references  funcao (id_funcao)
) engine = InnoDB; 

create table filmes_exibido_sala (
    fk_id_filmes int,
    fk_id_sala int,
    fk_id_horario int,
    constraint foreign key (fk_id_filmes) references filme (id_filme),
    constraint foreign key (fk_id_sala) references sala (id_sala),
    constraint foreign key (fk_id_horario) references  horario (id_horario)
)engine = InnoDB ;

create table filmes_has_premiacao (
    fk_id_filmes int primary key auto_increment,
    fk_id_premiacao int,
    ganhouBOOL varchar (45),
    constraint foreign key (fk_id_filmes) references filme (id_filme),
    constraint foreign key (fk_id_premiacao) references premiacao (id_premiacao)
)engine = InnoDB;
```

Comment: tente especificar mais o seu problema e identar o código para que fique mais fácil para a comunidade entender e assim tentar te ajudar =)

Answer (score 1):

Tem dois erros no seu *script*.

Primeiro, crie as tabelas sem chaves estrangeiras primeiro. Da forma como está, ao tentar criar a tabela `Filme` vai falhar dado que as tabelas `director` e `genero` ainda não existem.

Segundo, na sua tabela `Filme` chamou `id_filmes` à chave primária. No entanto, nas tabelas que se referem a `Filme` usou `id_filme` como chave primária da tabela estrangeira (isto é, tem um `s` a mais).

O seu *script* actualizado (e [a funcionar no SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2aad4)):

```
create table funcao (
    id_funcao int primary key auto_increment,
    nome varchar (45) not null
)engine = InnoDB;

create table horario (
    id_horario int primary key auto_increment,
    hora time not null
)engine = InnoDB;

create table sala (
    id_sala int primary key auto_increment,
    nome varchar (45) not null,
    capacidade int 
)engine = InnoDB;

create table premiacao (
    id_premiacao int primary key auto_increment,
    nome varchar (45) not null,
ano int 
)engine = InnoDB;

create table Funcionario (
    id_funcionario  int primary key auto_increment,
    nome varchar (45) not null,
    carteiraTrabalho int not null,
    dataContratacao date not null,
    salario float not null
)engine = InnoDB; 

create table diretor (
    id_diretor int primary key auto_increment,
    nome varchar (45) not null
)engine = InnoDB;

create table genero (
id_genero int primary key auto_increment,
nome varchar (45) not null
)engine = InnoDB;

create table Filme (
    id_filme int primary key auto_increment not null,
    nome_BR varchar (45) not null,
    nome_EN varchar (45) not null,
    anoLanccamento int not null,
    sinopse varchar (45) not null,
    fk_id_diretor int,
    fk_id_genero int,
    constraint foreign key (fk_id_diretor) references diretor (id_diretor),
    constraint foreign key (fk_id_genero) references genero (id_genero)
)engine = InnoDB;


create table horario_trabalho_funcionario(
    fk_id_horario int,
    fk_id_funcionario int,
    fk_id_funcao int ,
    constraint foreign key (fk_id_horario) references horario (id_horario),
    constraint foreign key (fk_id_funcionario) references funcionario (id_funcionario),
    constraint foreign key (fk_id_funcao) references  funcao (id_funcao)
) engine = InnoDB; 

create table filmes_has_premiacao (
    fk_id_filmes int primary key auto_increment,
    fk_id_premiacao int,
    ganhouBOOL varchar (45),
    constraint foreign key (fk_id_filmes) references filme (id_filme),
    constraint foreign key (fk_id_premiacao) references premiacao (id_premiacao)
)engine = InnoDB;

create table filmes_exibido_sala (
    fk_id_filmes int,
    fk_id_sala int,
    fk_id_horario int,
    constraint foreign key (fk_id_filmes) references filme (id_filme),
    constraint foreign key (fk_id_sala) references sala (id_sala),
    constraint foreign key (fk_id_horario) references  horario (id_horario)
)engine = InnoDB ;
```